# Is it okay to perform the same row operation twice on opposite rows?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am trying to find the inverse of the following matrix:

```
 1  2  3 
 2  1  4
 1  0  2
```

I draw the identity matrix next to it and start performing row operations.  After a few I get this matrix:

```
 1  2  3 |  1  0  0
 0 -3 -2 | -2  1  0
 0 -2 -1 | -1  0  1
```

I want to get a one in the middle of the middle row so I multiply the bottom row by -2 and add it to the middle row to get the following:

```
 1  2  3 |  1  0  0
 0  1  0 |  0  1 -2
 0 -2 -1 | -1  0  1
```

Then in order to get rid of the first -2 in the bottom row I perform exactly the reverse operation (multiplying the middle row by -2 and adding it to the bottom row) to get the following:

```
 1  2  3 |  1  0  0
 0  1  0 |  0  1 -2
 0  0 -1 | -1 -2  5
```

However, comparing this to the final matrix shown below, I will never be able to adjust the bottom row to compensate.  Was the operation I performed allowed or did I simply make a mistake?

```
 1  0  0 | -2  4 -5
 0  1  0 |  0  1 -2
 0  0  1 |  1 -2  3
```

Comment: In the last step, you want to multiply the middle row by $2$ and add to the last (or multiply by $-2$ and *subtract*).

Comment: Duh.  I knew it was something simple like that all along.  Case closed I guess, unless I'm still stuck after all that -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply made a mistake in row operations.  I had:

```
1  2  3 |  1  0  0
0  1  0 |  0  1 -2
0 -2 -1 | -1  0  1
```

In the next step, multiplying the middle row by 2 and adding to the bottom row, should give me

```
1  2  3 |  1  0  0
0  1  0 |  0  1 -2
0  0 -1 | -1  2 -3
```

Which I can then use to find the inverse (the correct solution is given in the question).